# What documents do I need to register my address in Tianhe District, Guangzhou, China?

Tags: legal, china

I plan to visit Guangzhou and stay in a friend's rented apartment. The friend has hukou in a different province. I will need to [register with the local police](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/37497/what-documentation-is-needed-to-register-in-china-with-local-police-when-staying).

I have heard that documentation for this varies not only city-to-city but also station to station. I am therefore looking to see if anyone has experience with police stations in Tianhe 天河区 District, Guangzhou.

Unfortunately, last time I was there, the police told us we needed an original building document, which the landlord had zero interest in providing. Thus, I ended up not registering on that trip. This time, however, I would like to follow the rules.

Has anyone successfully registered with a police station in Tianhe district, and can share what documentation you used?

Comment: Im not sure if its the same in Guangzhou, but in Shenzhen, apartments should have a QR code next to their door. You can use WeChat to scan the QR code, and a mini-app within WeChat will pop up and allow you to enter your personal information. From my experience, although you should follow the rules of course, this policy is hardly ever enforced. Technically you need to do it within 24 hours. I ended up doing it 2 weeks later, and my apt didnt even have a QR code, so the police just told me to find a neighbor who had one and scan his lol. Its necessary if you are coming for work though.

Answer (score 2):

This is one rule that is never enforced in China, it only matters if you plan to apply for work permit and visa in China as the temporary residence address paper is required so unless you are applying for visa or work permit you can skip this, if you get caught which is harder than winning the lotto you simply have to pay a 300 rmb fee and go to the police station with proof of address and passport, the proof of address in your case would be your friends rental contract or purchase contract in case of a bought apartment.

I have lived in China for 20 years plus and I only register when u need to renew my visa and work permit once a year